# Физика движения шайбы в глоу хоккее

Tags: физика

Пишу игру на MS DOS под названием "Glow Hockey". Всё написано, но нужно написать самую главную функцию - соприкосновения игрока и шайбы. Нужно чтобы она отлетала под правильной траекторией. Ума не приложу как вычислять углы и всё такое. Код кидать не вижу смысла, т.к. там около 600 строк. Прошу хотя бы на пальцах объяснить, мб используя другие константы, чтобы я понял и мог уже наконец-то закончить её.

Кидаю скрин, для понимая того, что у меня есть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7):

Простое отражение. Соединяешь центры шайбы и игрока в момент удара (синяя линия), строишь перпендикуляр к этой линии в точке контакта (зелёная).

Вектор скорости шайбы до столкновения отражается относительно синей линии.

К отраженному вектору шайбы прибавляется проекция вектора скорости игрока на синюю линию.

[image]

p.s. можно [погуглить](https://www.google.ru/search?q=air+hockey+collision+physics&source=lnms&tbm=isch) "Air hockey collision physics"

*Обновление*

В момент столкновения есть точка центра шайбы `S(x,y)`, вектор её скорости `Vs(x,y);` центр игрока `P(x,y)` и вектор скорости игрока `Vp(x,y)`.

Уравнение прямой через две точки `S и P`;

Спроецировать `Vp` на эту прямую = `SPVp`;

Спроецировать `Vs` на эту прямую = `SPVs`;

Спроецировать `Vs` на перпендикуляр к `SP = pSPVs`;

Новый вектор скорости шайбы: `SPVp - SPVs + pSPVs` (сумма векторов).

Comment: Спасибо, а можете объяснить на языке программирования? Условия столкновения понятно как сделать, но вот соединения центров..

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Угу. Это вопрос не к нам, это физика за 9-10 класс. Записываете закон сохранения импульса в векторной форме, возводите в квадрат, записываете закон сохранения энергии, получаете систему, решаете в векторной форме, профит.

Comment: как сделать так, чтобы при движении шайбы, движение игрока не тормозилось?!

Comment: @Tep4kill описанная модель так и считает: что игрок продолжит свое движение, как будто ничего не произошло. А шайба после удара ускорится - добавив к своей скорости часть скорости игрока.